# Mistake in Wikipedia Entry "Coalgebra"

Tags: coalgebras, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups

Consider the following quote from the Wikipedia entry *Coalgebra*:

> The kernel of every coalgebra morphism $f : C_1 \to C_2$ is a coideal in $C_1$, and the image is a subcoalgebra of $C_2$.

I can't see any qualifiers preceding or succeeding the statement. Am I missing something obvious here, or is this just plain wrong?

Do there not exists kernels of coalgebra maps that are not coideals?

Comment: There are lots of mistakes on Wikipedia.

Comment: Certainly if $f$ is a morphism of coalgebras, then $\Delta_{C_2}f(c_1) = (f\otimes f)(\Delta_{C_1}c_1) \in f(C_1) \otimes f(C_1)$, so that the image is a subcoalgebra.  Or am I confused?  The dual statement for algebras is that the coimage of an algebra morphism $A_1 \to A_2$ is a quotient algebra of $A_1$, which is also certainly true.  Incidentally, I've never liked the word "coideal" for this notion — a coideal _should_ be a _cokernel_ of a map.

Comment: Coalgebra morphisms are linear (i.e. vector space) morphisms that respect the comultiplication, so the image of a coalgebra is also a coalgebra. They also send the counit to the counit, so the image is a subcoalgebra of the codomain, once you restrict the counit.

Comment: @ Theo: Yes, you're right - stupid mistake on my part - I've edited accordingly. However, it still stands that the kernel of a coalgebra map need not be a coideal.

Comment: @Theo: I see at least three ways to define a "subcoalgebra" of a coalgebra $D$. The first is to define it as a $k$-submodule $M$ of $D$ satisfying $\Delta_D\left(M\right)\subseteq \left(\text{the image of the canonical map }M\otimes M\to D\otimes D\right)$. The second is to define it as a subobject in the category of coalgebras, i. e., a coalgebra $M$ with a coalgebra monomorphism $M\to D$. The third is to define it as a coalgebra $M$ with an injective coalgebra homomorphism (that's not the same as a monomorphism!) $M\to D$. Which of these are equivalent when $k$ is not a field? I don't know.

Comment: Okay, forget about the second way; it's probably an abuse of the word "subcoalgebra" even when $k$ is a field.

Comment: @Theo: half of the time, I think so too. But then a subcoalgebra of $C$ should be a quotient of $C$, and it becomes weird...

Comment: If you see a mathematical mistake on Wikipedia, it immediately becomes your fault if you don't click "edit" and fix it.

Comment: I suppose this thread counts as dead, but never mind. I don't understand Theo's argument that the image of a coalgebra is a coalgebra. How is your element not dependent on the choice of $c_1$? There may be no coherent lift of $\Delta$ on $im(f)$ to $im(f) \otimes im(f)$ unless $im(f) \otimes im(f) \to D \otimes D$ is injective.

Comment: I think that "coimage" may be an unfortunate coinage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the statement that a kernel is a coideal isn't treated in the comments let me give the following reference from Sweedler's book "Hopf Algebras":

Prop. 1.4.4: The image of a coalgebra morphism is a subcoalgebra

Theorem 1.4.7 b): If it's an coalgebra over a field, then the kernel of a coalgebra morphism is a coideal. (compare Gjergji's counterexample in the general case)

**Added:** An inspection of Sweedler's proof of Th. 1.4.7 b) shows that the crucial property is $\ker(f \otimes f) = \ker f \otimes C_1 + C_1 \otimes \ker f$. This always holds over a field but is usually false over a comm. ring. However, if $f$ is surjective this identity holds over any ring. In particular, over any comm. ground ring, the kernel of a surjective coalgebra morphism is a coideal.

For instance, in Gjergji's example $f$ isn't surjective since $\mathbb{Z}/4 \nsubseteq \operatorname{im}(f)$.

Comment: In Sweedler's book, one has a ground *field*, while in Gjergji's answer the coalgebra is a 'coring', really.

Comment: Yes, I should had quoted it properly. Thanks for the hint.  

Comment: @Mariano: Thanks for making the distinction between the two results. The Nichols - Sweedler example was the one that inspired my question. I got confused by  field/coring choice. 

Comment: Regarding your addendum: since the image of $f$ is a subcoalgebra, restricting the *codomain* of $f$ to it gives a surjective map with the same kernel. Something breaks, no?

Comment: I am missing something, I guess! If $f$ is Gjergji's map, then $f(C_1)$ is a coalgebra and the corestriction $f:C_1\to f(C_1)$ is surely a surjective coalgebra map, which happens to have the same kernel as $f$: its kernel, though, is not a coideal.

Comment: Well, here we go. Let $f:M \to M'',\; g:N \to N''$ be two homs of $R$-modules, $R$ any ring. Let $M'$ be the image of $f$ and let $f': M \to M', m \mapsto f(m)$. Let $i:M' \hookrightarrow M''$. Define $N', g', j$ similarly. Then 
$$f \otimes g = (i \otimes j) \circ (f' \otimes g'): M \otimes N \twoheadrightarrow M' \otimes N' \to M'' \otimes N''$$
and $$\ker(f' \otimes g') = \ker(f) \otimes  N + M \otimes \ker(g) $$. But since $i \otimes j$ isn't injective in general, the kernel of $f \otimes g$ may be larger then the kernel of $f' \otimes g'$. 


Comment: @Mariano, the tensor product of injective maps may fail to be injective, so "happens to have the same kernel" doesn't always hold.

Comment: Oh, I see Ralph already explained this...

Comment: I understand that. But are you saying that the kernel of the correstriction $f:C_1\to f(C_1)$ in the context of G's example is not the same as that of $f:C_1\to C_2$? There is no tensor product involved in this question :/

Comment: Maybe my problem is that I am reading the sentence "if $f$ is surjective it also holds over any comm. ring" in your addendum to mean that it is true that the kernel of a surjective coalgebra map is a coideal, with no hypothesis on the ground ring.

Comment: No, if $f': C_1 \to f(C_1)$, then I'm saying that the kernel of $f' \otimes f'$ is not the same as that of $f \otimes f$. 

Comment: Concerning your last comment: Yes exactly, if $f$ is surjective then $\ker(f)$ is a coideal whatever the , say comm., ground ring is. 

Comment: So that means that while the kernel of $f:C_1\to C_2$ is not a coideal of $C_1$, the kernel of $f':C_1\to f(C_1)$ is. 

Comment: Yes, to my understanding. 

Comment: No, it doesn't. What is true is that $\Delta\left(\mathrm{Ker} f\right)\subseteq \mathrm{Ker}\left(f\otimes f\right)$ because of $\Delta\circ f=\left(f\otimes f\right)\circ \Delta$. You are trying to prove $\Delta\left(\mathrm{Ker} f^{\prime}\right)\subseteq \mathrm{Ker}\left(f^{\prime}\otimes f^{\prime}\right)$, but this is not true in general, since we don't have an equation of the form $\Delta^{\prime}\circ f=\left(f^{\prime}\otimes f^{\prime}\right)\circ \Delta$ anymore (in fact, $f\left(C_1\right)$ needs not have a coproduct).

Comment: The reason for this I have explained in my comments under the question: There are two non-equivalent notions of a subcoalgebra, and $f\left(C_1\right)$ satisfies only one of them, while only the other has a well-defined coproduct.

Comment: darij, it's good to know that you are taking part in the thread. 

Answer (score 5):

Theo already proved in the comments that the image of a coalgebra map is always a subcoalgebra of the codomain. Here is an example where the kernel is not a coideal, taken from Nichols and Sweedler's "Hopf Algebras and Combinatorics" (also exercise 2.15.5 in "Corings and Comodules" by Brzeziński and Wisbauer):

Let $C_1=\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z$ with $c_0=(1,0,0),c_1=(0,1,0),c_2=(0,0,1)$ and
$$\Delta(c_0)=c_0\otimes c_0$$
$$\Delta(c_1)=c_0\otimes c_1+c_1\otimes c_0$$
$$\Delta(c_2)=c_0\otimes c_2+c_1\otimes c_1+c_2\otimes c_0$$ 
Let $C_2=\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ with $d_0=(1,0),d_1=(0,1)$ and
$$\Delta(d_0)=d_0\otimes d_0$$
$$\Delta(d_1)=d_0\otimes d_1+d_1\otimes d_0$$
Now take the coalgebra map $f: C_1\to C_2$ that sends $$c_0\to d_0,c_1\to 2d_1,c_2\to 0,$$
its kernel is $c_2\mathbb Z$. However $c_2\in \operatorname{ker}(f)$ but $\Delta(c_2)\notin c_2\otimes C_1+C_1\otimes c_2$ so the kernel of $f$ is not a coideal.

Comment: What is the kernel of $f'$? I am surely messing up my calculation... :(

Comment: I think $\Delta(c_2) \in \ker(f)$ should be $c_2 \in \ker(f)$. Also note that $\ker(f') = \ker(f)$. 

Comment: Thanks guys, I got confused on the calculations there for a moment.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a counterexample to show that the image of a coalgebra map isn't always a coalgebra (adapted from the Nichols-Sweedler counterexamples).

Let $C = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ with $\Delta(e_1) = 0$, $\Delta(e_2)=e_1 \otimes e_1$ and $D = \mathbb{Z}/8 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2$ with $\Delta(f_1) = 0$, $\Delta(f_2) = 4f_1 \otimes f_1$. (Here $e_i$ and $f_i$ denote the standard generators). Define a map $f\colon C \to D$ by $f(e_1) = 2f_1$ and $f(e_2) = f_2$. That's a coalgebra map.

Now the image of $f$ is $\mathbb{Z}/4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2$, I'm calling the generators $\overline e_1$ and $\overline e_2$. But it's not a sub-coalgebra. Any lift of $4f_1 \otimes f_1 = \Delta(f_2)$ to $im(f) \otimes im(f)$ would have to have order $4$, but $\overline e_2$ and $f_2$ only have order $2$.

These are non-counital coalgebras, but they can easily be made counital by taking the direct sum with $\mathbb{Z}$ and interpreting the above-defined $\Delta$ map as reduced coproduct $\overline\Delta$.